# Create new plots to get user input in a loop and keep another open to update statistics using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The problem I'm trying to solve is as follows: **I want to iteratively create new plots on which the user can interact (e.g. click on a subplot to mark an answer as correct) and a single plot that updates the statistics from the user input**. Let's call the former `Plot A` and the latter `Plot B`.

Specifically:

- `Plot A` contains a set of subplots generated from a given input, on which the user is prompted to select one subplot. `Plot A` will be created every time we receive a new input file and is closed by the user when they finish selecting, after which their answers are updated on `Plot B`. I wrote an event handler and attached it to `Plot A` to record the mouse clicks.
- `Plot B`, once shown after the first user input, remains open and the statistics will be updated every time we receive new user input from `Plot A`

As the program I'm doing has several classes (`PlotA` created by one class and `PlotB` by another), I'll summarize it with this simple pipeline:

```
for new input X from folder:
    plotA(X)  # new plot is created for an input X, user clicks on subplots in plotA
    update_plotB()
```

where:

```
def plotA(X):
    # do computation on X
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows..., ncols=..., figsize=(...))
    ...plotting stuff...
    plt.show()
```

and

```
def update_plotB():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(num='plotB', ncols=..., nrows=..., figsize=...)  # I set an ID for plotB
    for row, col:
         ax[row, col].plot(...)   # update the statistics in each subplot
    plt.show()
```

So I wish that a new `PlotA` is created for every new input, blocks the program until the user closes the plot themselves, afterward the subplots in `PlotB` are updated/redrawn with new answers.

What I have tried so far (after reading lots of topics on SO):

#### (1) Using `plt.ion()`

I put `plt.ion()` at the beginning of the program. But it ended up showing every plot at once without blocking the program for user input in `PlotA` (the code runs too fast the program ends before I can see anything plotted).

#### (2) Using `plt.show(block=False)` in `update_plotB()`

This works fine only once (that is, `PlotB` is shown without blocking in the 1st iteration), but then `PlotB` blocks in all the following iterations - which I find really strange but don't know why.

#### (3) Replacing `plt.show()` in `update_plotB` by `plt.draw()` or `plt.pause(0.05)` (without `plt.ion()`)

`PlotB` blocks the execution until I close it, then new `PlotB` is created in every iteration.

---

I hope I've explained it clear enough. Thank you very much in advance!